# How to make a website open automatically in a certain language based on user's location?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, internationalization

I have a multilingual website, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it open automatically in a certain language based on user's location... Could someone refer me to the article or website which describes this?

P.S. I'm using WordPress

Comment: Just make sure you add the option for a user to change the language manually, people do travel and/or use proxies.

Comment: It's called Geolocation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation

Comment: +1 for @TheZ's comment. Sites drive me nuts when they don't give me an option to change language, and even more nuts when they don't remember my choice or they keep randomly switching back.

Comment: You use a plugin for Wordpress to make it multilingual, like http://wpml.org/ ?

Comment: If you use WPML as you say in one of the comments, then you simply need to go throught the WPML settings. This gives you various ways to do the switching, and these can be combined. On our sites we use automatic language detection, so the user is redirect to their browser language. Then we also enable the option to add a link at the end of every post. Additionally we have WPML place language associated flags at the bottom of every page. Its discrete but also very clear to the user, should they be faced with a page in the wrong language for them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the Multi-language switcher plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a Plugin for WP as mentioned above. WP does not support multilingual websites by default.
Automatically displaying the right language is not wrong, as long as you have an option for the user to change the language.

The Pro Version should have language detection, but not sure if it is available yet: 
https://github.com/inpsyde/multilingual-press

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Yes, I'm using WPML plugin and I'm giving an option to change the language. I just need an option of making website open in the "right" language based on location or browser settings. I'll check the plugins you've recommended.